# Finding a differential equation for $r=x\tan(x+c)$

Tags: calculus, matrix-equations, differential

I found this problem in a textbook

Find a differential equation whose solution is the $n$-parameter family

$$r=x\tan(x+c)$$

The textbook says that $xr'= r + r^2 + x^2$ I'd a differential equation that works. I took the first derivative to get

$$ r' = \tan (x+c) + x\sec ^2(x+c)$$

Then I multiplied both sides by x and substituted $r$ for $x\tan (x+c)$ to get

$$xr' = r + [x\sec (x+c)]^2$$

I just don't know how the secants term in this equation seemingly becomes $r^2 + x^2$. Can anyone explain why that is or spot any errors in what I've done so far?

Comment: Where are the $n$ parameters? I only see one.

Comment: I think that is just a general instruction for a problem set. Other problems had more c values

Comment: Regardless of the "general instruction for a problem set", you should take responsibility for asking the Question in a clear way.  If you are merely passing along an assigned exercise from someone else with no effort to understand what you are asking, you are not contributing excellent content.  Please review [ask]?

Comment: Here I thought this was a place to ask questions and help people by answering them. Guess it's a place for people to be petty and passive agressive

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I remembered to apply a trig identity to put $(\sec x)^2$ in terms of $\tan x$ and used that to write $\tan x$ in terms of $r$ to eliminate the $c$.